# While joining two table, how to keep columns that have different names, dropping those with identical names?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Using `dplyr::left_join()` it is possible to join tables while using a vector to tell which columns have to be used.

I try to join two tables using :

- columns that have the same name and,
- columns that have different names.

I would like to keep the columns, from both tables, that have different names in the ouput.

The argument `keep = TRUE` does not permit to differentiate the columns to keep.

```r
# example
dplyr::left_join(
  dplyr::select(head(mtcars), vs, am, gear), 
  dplyr::select(tail(mtcars), vs, am, carb, qsec), 
  by = c("vs", "am", "gear" = "carb")) # column carb is dropped
#>   vs am gear qsec
#> 1  0  1    4 14.5
#> 2  0  1    4 14.5
#> 3  1  1    4   NA
#> 4  1  0    3   NA
#> 5  0  0    3   NA
#> 6  1  0    3   NA

# not the solution
dplyr::left_join(
  dplyr::select(head(mtcars), vs, am, gear), 
  dplyr::select(tail(mtcars), vs, am, carb, qsec), 
  by = c("vs", "am", "gear" = "carb"),
  keep = TRUE) # columns that have the same name are duplicated
#>   vs.x am.x gear vs.y am.y carb qsec
#> 1    0    1    4    0    1    4 14.5
#> 2    0    1    4    0    1    4 14.5
#> 3    1    1    4   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 4    1    0    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 5    0    0    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 6    1    0    3   NA   NA   NA   NA

# Expected output :
data.frame(
  vs = c(0,0,1,1,0,1),
  am = c(1,1,0,0,0,0),
  gear = c(4,4,4,3,3,3),
  carb = c(4,4,NA,NA,NA, NA),
  qsec = c(14.5,14.5,NA,NA,NA, NA)
)
#>   vs am gear carb qsec
#> 1  0  1    4    4 14.5
#> 2  0  1    4    4 14.5
#> 3  1  0    4   NA   NA
#> 4  1  0    3   NA   NA
#> 5  0  0    3   NA   NA
#> 6  1  0    3   NA   NA
```

Note: it is possible to use the argument `suffix = c("", ".y")` and then select columns with `dplyr::select(!dplyr::ends_with(".y"))` but I fell like I am missing a shorter way without the "select" step.

```r
library(magrittr)
dplyr::left_join(
  dplyr::select(head(mtcars), vs, am, gear), 
  dplyr::select(tail(mtcars), vs, am, carb, qsec), 
  by = c("vs", "am", "gear" = "carb"),
  keep = TRUE,
  suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  dplyr::select(!dplyr::ends_with(".y"))
#>   vs am gear carb qsec
#> 1  0  1    4    4 14.5
#> 2  0  1    4    4 14.5
#> 3  1  1    4   NA   NA
#> 4  1  0    3   NA   NA
#> 5  0  0    3   NA   NA
#> 6  1  0    3   NA   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Where is the point of merging/joining on ambiguous variables?

Comment: @jay.sf what do you mean by "ambiguous"? In my real case, I would like to use this feature to merge two date columns. One has every days within a time period and the other one has only punctual events. I need to keep the column of "events" for latter use.

Comment: _Ambiguous_ is defined as "making several interpretations plausible", if your real date columns are each without duplicates, it would make more sense than the example in the OP.

Comment: @jay.sf the example has no point when it comes to the reason of joining but is shows what I try to do. The question is all about dropping or preserving columns with `dplyr::left_join()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not much better, but

```r
select(tail(mtcars), vs, am, carb, qsec) %>%
  mutate(gear = carb) %>%
  left_join(select(head(mtcars), vs, am, gear), ., by = c("vs", "am", "gear"))
#   vs am gear carb qsec
# 1  0  1    4    4 14.5
# 2  0  1    4    4 14.5
# 3  1  1    4   NA   NA
# 4  1  0    3   NA   NA
# 5  0  0    3   NA   NA
# 6  1  0    3   NA   NA
```

The changes: removed `keep=TRUE`, and duplicated `carb` into `gear` so that the join would not remove the joined-on column.